# What is the difference between my HMAC-512 and Python's official HMAC-512?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, hmac, sha512

This is the python code I have been asked to do for my Cryptography assignment, that is to implement the official HMAC function from RFC2104

```
from hashlib import sha512
b = 512 #block size of SHA-512

def HMAC(key, message, h, b) :
    #This function proceeds to do the 7 Hmac steps as defined in RFC 2104
    #opad and ipad initialization
    B = b//8 #The number of bytes of h output
    ipad = 0x36
    opad = 0x5c

    #Step 1 : we manage to set the key to B bytes
    if len(key) > b :
        k = bytearray((h(k).digest())) #By hashing it if it's too long
    else :
        k = key + bytearray(B - len(key)) #Or by padding the right of k with zeros
    print(k, len(k))

    #We compute kXORopad and kXORipad by doing byte by byte XOR
    kXopad = bytearray(B) #Bytearray of size B
    kXipad = bytearray(B)
    for i in range(B) :
        kXipad[i] ^= ipad;
        kXopad[i] ^= opad;
    
    sub_result = h() #Here we are doing the right side of the equation
    sub_result.update(kXipad)
    sub_result.update(message)
    print(kXipad, len(kXipad))
    print(sub_result.digest())

    sub_result = bytearray(sub_result.digest())

    result = h()
    result.update(kXopad)
    print(kXopad, len(kXopad))
    print(result.digest())
    result.update(sub_result)

    #We will return an int
    return result.hexdigest()

#We deal with bytes 
message = "a"#This input string is being used to test my own implementation of HMAC-SHA-512."
key = "a"
my_Hmac = HMAC(key.encode(), message.encode(), sha512, b)
print(my_Hmac)

import hmac
official_hmac = hmac.new(key.encode(), message.encode(), digestmod = sha512)
print(official_hmac.name)
print(official_hmac.hexdigest())
print(my_Hmac == official_hmac.hexdigest())
```

This is the output of my hmac hexdigest() :
4f330db94c708a6c6b54b009e48c54a1fa1e2fad77728c2d6c28fcdb7f702fa572ea928da2154537b7cef8f4f0389cfa9c7b67ebad21b445e58c228ead9e8c15

This is the output of Python's hmac hexdigest() :
b37ee7821bf96e293def120539070a3010f69c37a247bb4bc1344d3491b89844525519df30d89a49d2537905b30cfa7f3a6ee54324eb1c280af5a747f3baaac5

Also, I found a website calculating HMAC, and this is the output from https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#before-output with sha512 :
fc8c80e6b943cd07eccecf01bc6038bae68ebb6fa2e1e62b44753d7c177af7a46b089df349a19f7622a22312c76906ca9c984e1446d3ab86a98fdfa1425341c5

Python's "hmac" library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html) says its HMAC is as it is defined in RFC2104 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2104.html). I looked that up and tried to do every step of the algorithm one by one :  H(K XOR opad, H(K XOR ipad, text))
Could anyone tell me what I did wrong that differs from the official version of HMAC? Maybe I failed importing hmac? Maybe both
Thank you very much

Comment: First of all, there is a bug regarding the HMAC of the Python library: There is no `update()` call, i.e. the message is not specified at all. If this is fixed (s. https://www.online-python.com/idyQT6JZYX), the result is the same as that of the website. It's only the result of your implementation that differs (which is therefore probably buggy)! BTW, RFC 2104 defines test vectors, though not for SHA512, but it still makes sense to test against the official test vectors as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for that clarification! I figured there was also a message parameter i could fill in the hmac.new method, that automatically updates. 
Regarding my implementation, do you have any idea what part is causing the result to change?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't take a closer look at the code. You should use test vectors with *intermediate* results. This way you may be able to isolate the problem, see e.g. [NIST - Examples with intermediate values](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-standards-and-guidelines/example-values), especially [HMAC_SHA512](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/HMAC_SHA512.pdf).

Comment: It's alright, I found out that not being a native english speaker and being tired got me block-size and output-size confused, my problem is solved :) thank you for your help :)